# Terraform - Provision VM Extensions with Parameters

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm trying to provision two `Azure` Virtual Machine `Extensions`, that have parameters associated to them:

1. Microsoft Antimalware
2. Site24x7 Agent for Windows Server Monitoring

I could not find much documentation, but I tried to extract the data from the azure portal under `Automation script` to see how it was setup in JSON template.

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "test1" {
name                 = "IaaSAntimalware"
location             = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.location}"
resource_group_name  = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.name}"
virtual_machine_name = "${azurerm_virtual_machine.testapp.name}"
publisher            = "Microsoft.Azure.Security"
type                 = "IaaSAntimalware"
type_handler_version = "1.5.5.1"
auto_upgrade_minor_version = "true"

settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
        "AntimalwareEnabled": true,
        "RealtimeProtectionEnabled": "true",
        "ScheduledScanSettings": {
            "isEnabled": "true",
            "day": "1",
            "time": "120",
            "scanType": "Quick"
            },
        "Exclusions": {
            "Extensions": "",
            "Paths": "",
            "Processes": ""
            }
    }
SETTINGS

tags {
    environment = "${var.tag_env}" }
}
```

[Azure Portal Configuration for Antimalware Extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Plng.png)

> azurerm_virtual_machine_extension.test1: 1 error(s) occurred:`
>
> azurerm_virtual_machine_extension.test1: compute.VirtualMachineExtensionsClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=400 Code="InvalidParameter" Message="The value of parameter typeHandlerVersion is invalid."

Does anyone know the proper syntax?

Comment: I'm also trying the same thing with Site24x7 Agent:  

` "settings": {  `
       "site24x7AgentType": "azurevmextnwindowsserver"  
                  },  
      "protectedSettings": { "site24x7LicenseKey": "  }  
            }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at [this line](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/4a9cc36257ab8f16d37ea2176a41241657fdb9c5/anti-malware-extension-windows-vm/azuredeploy.json#L245) in the anti-malware-extension-windows-vm sample of azure-quickstart-templates: `"typeHandlerVersion": "1.1",` you see that you are passing the wrong value for the version.